# How to manage users on many sites under one Drupal Installation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I work for a government organization and we are trying to move to Drupal. My job right now is to figure out the best way to limit access to content based on a user and their roles.

The big issue I have not yet figured out is this:

If we want to have many different sites for many different departments each with their own users. Can we limit access to content and taxonomy terms (and really anything at all that one department should or should not see) all on the same site? In my research it seems like this is possible but it involves the creation of many, many different content types and roles and basically making one massive Drupal site.

Is this the best way to go? Is it better to have one site with many nodes or many sites? If many sites is the way to go will they all still have the same domain? (ie: www.government.com/parks , www.government.com/police, etc...)

If anyone has some insight or resources about this issue I would be very appreciative. I am willing to buy books or other resources (within reason) if they are worthwhile resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with having different subdomains for different departments. [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) would be helpful in that case. In this case, the code base would be same for all subdomains (as there would be only one drupal installation) but the users are considered different. This is because each domain is given a unique domain id and that differentiates.

[Video on Domain Access Module](http://archive.org/details/SharingcontentacrossmultiplesiteswithDomainAccess)

Go through the project page of the module and you can get more details. Hope this helps you.